# How to register event handler safe in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, events, bluetooth-lowenergy, handler

Im am working an bluetooth low energy desktop windows application for a custom bluetooth service. The device sending the data was tested with Android applications. Now I am working on a windows library in C# to receive messages from the device. The service on the Microcontroller is based on the Atmel CSC service. The microcontroller uses the notification service to establish a serial chat between Client and Server.

My application always crashes with `exit code -1073740791 (0xc0000409)`. This exit code is caused by a stack overrun `(STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN (0xc0000409))`. This is related to a `/gs` exception. The application receives data for several seconds before it crashes (~5-30seconds?).

This issue occurs when I am registering an event handler for the Bluetooth GATT notify service.

```
characteristic.ValueChanged += CharacteristicValueChangedRequested;
```

The event handler looks like:

```
        private void CharacteristicValueChangedRequested(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //GattNotifyCharacteristic_sender.ValueChanged -= CharacteristicValueChangedRequested_Async;
        if (args.CharacteristicValue != null)
        {
            var length = args.CharacteristicValue.Length;
            if (length > 0)
            {
                if (length < 120)
                {
                    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue);
                    LatestClientMessage = reader.ReadString(length);
                    ClientMessages.Add(LatestClientMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        //GattNotifyCharacteristic_sender.ValueChanged += CharacteristicValueChangedRequested_Async;
    }
```

If I do not register the event handler for received messages the application is stable. If I register an empty event handler with no code the application also crashes with the same exit code. I'll try to receive about 100 notifications per second. The application is a bit more stable if I ll try to receive fewer data.

I ll tried different methods to register an event handler, but I think somehow I need to manage the same event handler being called multiple times.

I also tried to unregister the event handler immediately when called and reregister when finished, but that does not help a lot.

The characteristic is of type GattCharacteristic

```
GattCharacteristic
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
```

The registration for the notify service is done by the following code:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Register for Notification at BLE Device
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address"></param>
    /// <param name="Msg"></param>
    public async Task<string> RegisterNotificationForced_Async(ulong address)
    {
        var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address);
        var mGattDeviceServicesResult = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();
        GattCommunicationStatus result = GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable;

        foreach (var service in mGattDeviceServicesResult.Services)
        {
            if (service.Uuid == mGuid) //Atmel CSC Service
            {
                var mGattCharacteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(); //Characteristic on BLE Device
                if (mGattCharacteristicsResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    var characteristics = mGattCharacteristicsResult.Characteristics;
                    foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
                    {
                        if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
                        {
                            characteristic.ValueChanged += CharacteristicValueChangedRequested;

                            GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue DescriptorVal;
                            DescriptorVal = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify;
                            result = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(DescriptorVal);
                            if (result != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                                throw new System.ArgumentException("Failed to register notification at BLE Device");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Characteristics on BLE device not found");
                }
            }
        }
        return $"{result}";
    }
```

The problem  might be related to the windows bluetooth driver and the event handler registered there....

Thank you for your comments...

Comment: What is `characteristic`? It sounds like it's an issue with whatever is publishing that event, but you haven't told us what that is

Comment: GattCharacteristic using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile I am registering for notification using the notify property. I am receiving data but the application crahes after several seconds.

Comment: You need to introduce your question with a context. Your question is concerning Bluetooth on some special devices running Windows. You need to explain what you are doing and what the purpose is. Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: I thought the problem might be related to the eventhandler being called multiple times. Maybe the handler can be registered as delegate or like thread to provide different instances.. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Much better explanation of your problem :)

Comment: Any ideas? I also do not know how to track the gs exception? In C++ unsafe can be used to avoid the exception. Is there any similar possibilty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to really find the issue related to the problem. The problem does not exist when using the nuget package microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform. At least I found a workaround. Before I was using Microsoft.Windows.SDK Contracts. The new code is based on the following example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothle/